# django-python: NoReverseMatch issue: what argument should I give it?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the following views:

```
def default_detail (request, equipment_id):
    equipment = Equipment.objects.get(id = equipment_id)
    context = {'equipment' : equipment}
    return render(request, 'calbase/default_detail.html', context)


def default_add_cal (request, equipment_id):
    equipment = get_object_or_404(Equipment, id = equipment_id)
    EquipmentInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Equipment, Calibration, fields = ('cal_by', 'cal_date', 'notes'), extra = 1, )
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'calibration' in request.POST:
            formset = EquipmentInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=equipment)
            if formset.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('calbase:default_detail', args=(equipment_id)))
    else:
        formset = EquipmentInlineFormSet(instance=equipment)
    return render(request, 'calbase/default_detail_cal.html', {'formset' : formset, 'equipment' : equipment})
```

And urls are like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.default, name = 'default'),
    url(r'^default/(?P<equipment_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.default_detail, name = 'default_detail'),
    url(r'^default/new/$', views.default_new, name = 'default_new'),
    url(r'^default/(?P<equipment_id>[0-9]+)/cal/$', views.default_add_cal, name = 'default_add_cal'),
]
```

and the template for default_add_cal, default_detail_cal.html is like :

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action = "{% url 'calbase:default_add_cal' equipment.id %}">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" name = "calibration">Save</button>
     </form>

<a href="{% url 'calbase:default' %}">Back?</a>
{% endblock %}
```

So Calibration is a foreign key to Equipment: a equipment can have several calibrations, and here I am trying to use a inlineformset to let user add calibrations to a equipment. Problem is that I got this:

> NoReverseMatch at /calbase/default/41/cal/
>   Reverse for 'default_detail' with arguments '('4', '1')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['calbase/default/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

It confuses me that for example, for equipment id =41, when I do

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('calbase:default_detail', args=(equipment_id)))
```

the argument that is actually passed is '('4', '1')' instead of 41. How could this be? How should I possibly fix this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the arguments as a tuple. That would make `args` an iterable with `equipment_id` being one of the arguments:

```
args=(equipment_id,‌​)
#                 ^
```

Those grouping parenthesis will not make the arguments a tuple:

```
>>> args = (42)
>>> type(args)
<class 'int'>
>>>
>>> args = (42,)
>>> type(args)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Works even without the parens:

```
>>> args = 42,
>>> type(args)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Thanks! that solved my problem. Could you please elaborate a bit more about the function of this "," please?

Comment: @HansongLi That's how tuples are defined. To make a singleton tuple, you'll need to add that comma. I added some code. Let me know if that's enough